# Swiping on a tableview is deselecting all selected rows trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Recently implemented `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` , where after swiping from right to left showing two options and its working fine. But the problem is when i select multiple rows or single row, after swiping the row/s they are getting deselected. Is there a way to keep the selection even after swiping?

Below is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->  UISwipeActionsConfiguration?  {

    let renameAction  = contextualToggleRenameAction(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    let lastResAction = contextualToggleLastResponseAction(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

    let swipeConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [renameAction, lastResAction])
    swipeConfig.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return swipeConfig
}

func contextualToggleLastResponseAction(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let sensorData = sensorsList?[indexPath.row]
    var lastResponse = ""
    if sensorData != nil{
        if let lstRes = sensorData!["last_response"] as? String{
            lastResponse = lstRes
        }
    }
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: lastResponse) { (contextAction: UIContextualAction, sourceView: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Last Response Action")
    }
    action.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 61/255, green: 108/255, blue: 169/255, alpha: 1.0)
    return action
}
```

Comment: The possible solution is to override `setSelected()` method of UITableViewCell`

Comment: @andrew.turkin I am overriding that, not sure how that would solve this, and at least it does not for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Holy crap, I fixed this stupid issue.

Yes, yes make sure tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true and tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true.

But...

Shout-out to this SO answer which almost directly led me on the way to success ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275337/uitableview-swiping-rowaction-cancels-the-selected-rows)).

KEY: Re-select/de-select the rows in your implementation of setEditing, which is a method you override. UITableView goes into editing mode when swiping.

IMPORTANT NOTE: Call super.setEditing(...) before any of your code, as shown below, or it likely won't work, or at least not perfectly.

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    for i in 0..<your data.count {
        if this item is selected {
            self.tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        } else {
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0), animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A swipe is considered as an edit, so you can enable `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` if you want to keep the selected state:

```swift
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Comment: Hey @Thomas, i tried by setting true to both tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing and allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on `indexPathsForSelectedRows` doesn't always give the expected result.

Instead you should maintain and array of `selectedIndexPaths`.

Here is a code snippet to demonstrate:

```
var selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
       selectedIndexPaths.removeAll { (ip) -> Bool in
        return ip == indexPath
    }else{
       selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you doing `removeAll ` ??

Comment: I am not removing all, I am just removing the already selected indexPath by implementing **where** clause predicate.  
`public mutating func removeAll(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows`

Comment: @jshivam, ok after saving indexpaths, when should i reselect all rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this :

1. Create array in your controller for selected index

   ```
   var arrSelectedIndex : [Int] = []
   ```
2. In `didSelect`,

   ```
   if arrSelectedIndex.contains(indexPath.row) { // Check index is selected or not
       // If index selected, remove index from array
       let aIndex = arrSelectedIndex.firstIndex(of: indexPath.row)
       arrSelectedIndex.remove(at: aIndex!)
   }
   else {
       // If index not selected, add index to array
       arrSelectedIndex.append(indexPath.row)
   }
   // reload selected row, or reloadData()
   self.tblView.reloadRows([indexPath.row], with: .automatic)
   ```

> Edit

3. In `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`,

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
   {

       if self.arrSelectedIndex.contains(indexPath.row) {

           let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (action, view, handler) in

           }
           action.backgroundColor = .green
           let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [])
           configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
           return configuration
       }
       let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Selected") { (action, view, handler) in

       }
       action.backgroundColor = .green
       let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
       configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
       return configuration
   }
   ```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @ShivaKumar What you doing with selected or deselected? Does it is deselected when cell is swiped or after swipe is done? Explain

Comment: i need the cells to be selected (i have multi selection enabled). As soon as i swipe all the previous selections are getting unselected.
FYI : In this case "didDeselectRowAt" is not getting called.

Comment: Added +50 for trying to help me. Thanks.

Comment: @ShivaKumar Does it worked for you or not?? Bcz I tried here and it worked properly.

Comment: No it didn't worked, i was able to convince my client and removed swiping feature :)

Comment: @ShivaKumar No problem bro.. 

Comment: @ShivaKumar Can you please check Output for future reference?